# Iterating over memory layer to run processing algorithm using Python in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, iteration

I am trying to write a python script that iterates over the features of a layer, selects a features and feeds into processing.runalg(). I am pretty sure the selection is going on. However, the processing.runalg("qgis:xxx") bit ocurrs oblivious to the selection! I know there are plenty of similar questions and answers, but I have tried their suggestions and haven't been successful. I though maybe if someone sees the code maybe could help me resolve this.

Here is the code (indents in the for loops might be messed up from formatting):

```
inter_shpmemory = iface.addVectorLayer(main_directory + "\\" + 
intersect_shpname,"Zone layer",labtype)
specieslayer_mem = iface.addVectorLayer(main_directory + "\\" + 
bd_shpname,"GBIF layer",labtype)

###Create a folder to safe all stuff
newfolder = main_directory + "\\" + "Zonal_GBIF"

if not os.path.exists(newfolder):
    os.makedirs(newfolder)


it = specieslayer_mem.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest() )
inputLayerIds = [i.id() for i in it]
#selects all of the input feature and one feature from the clip layer
specieslayer_mem.setSelectedFeatures( inputLayerIds )###is this even 
#needed?



features = inter_shpmemory.getFeatures()

for feature in features:
            indbd_name = feature['simp_name']
            inter_shpmemory.setSelectedFeatures([feature.id()])
            print "Feature ID %d: " % feature.id()
            print indbd_name
            processing.runalg('qgis:clip', specieslayer_mem, inter_shpmemory, newfolder + '\\' + indbd_name +'.shp')  
            inter_shpmemory.setSelectedFeatures([])

specieslayer_mem.setSelectedFeatures([])
```

I can't get to do it what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be that, you have to save the selection first.
I guess the 'qgis:clip' does not care with the selection.
Add this line too, and reload the saved layer with an other line:

`QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( layer, path + 'admpoly/' + name + ".shp", "system", crs, "ESRI Shapefile", 1)`

Comment: Thanks pnz. I will try this. I had considered that as a potential solution, but I first wanted to check with more knowledgeable people.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making lists, if you want to select all features in a layer, you could use:

```
layer.selectAll()
```

Conversely, if you want to remove all selections, you could use:

```
layer.removeSelection()
```

---

So in order to get your code to work, you could try using:

```
inter_shpmemory = iface.addVectorLayer(main_directory + "/" + 
intersect_shpname,"Zone layer",labtype)
specieslayer_mem = iface.addVectorLayer(main_directory + "/" + 
bd_shpname,"GBIF layer",labtype)

###Create a folder to safe all stuff
newfolder = main_directory + "/" + "Zonal_GBIF"

if not os.path.exists(newfolder):
    os.makedirs(newfolder)

specieslayer_mem.selectAll()

features = inter_shpmemory.getFeatures()
for feature in features:
    indbd_name = feature['simp_name']
    inter_shpmemory.setSelectedFeatures([feature.id()])
    print "Feature ID %d: " % feature.id()
    print indbd_name
    processing.runalg('qgis:clip', specieslayer_mem, inter_shpmemory, newfolder + '/' + indbd_name +'.shp')  
    inter_shpmemory.removeSelection()

specieslayer_mem.removeSelection()
```

---

Note that the "**Use only selected features**" option must be enabled in:

```
Processing > Options > General > Use only selected features
```

Comment: Joseph: I just gave it another try. I set up the Processing options and improved the selection code. Similar as the situation I had, the clip is happens, however it does not respond to the selection. In that respecti, PNZ's solution seems to work better than the one you provided. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @SebasCaTi - Most welcome, glad you got it to work :)